# How can i generate random DNS names of Hosts in java

Tags: java

this could be of the form:

aaa1.bbb2.ccc3.ddd4

Maybe taking a cue from http://www.dnsjava.org/download/
and first generating individual strings aaaa1 , bbb2 etc and then using join()

or

```
String validCharacters = $('a', 'z').join() + $('A', 'Z').join();

String randomString(int length) {
    return $(validCharacters).shuffle().slice(length).toString();
}

@Test
public void buildFiveRandomStrings() {
    for (int i : $(5)) {
        System.out.println(randomString(12));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just generate 2, 3 or more valid random strings that would represent subdomain(s) and domain.
Maybe then randomly pick a tld (.com,.net,.gov....) and then join them all with "." separator. Shouldn't be to hard.